# Python variables within a string syntax issue?

Tags: python, string, variables, python-3.x, syntax-error

I am making code for a program that determines attributes for a character, I want my program to `print` in the style or 'char1 has a strength value of str1 and a skill value of skl1' I looked for a way to do this in Python 3.3.2 and found this however I keep on getting an error while running it like this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CA2 solution.py", line 6, in <module>
    print('% has a strength value of % and a skill value of %'(char1,strh1,skl1))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I don't know what this is and it is hindering my progress, this is the code;

```
import random

char1=str(input('Please enter a name for character 1: '))
strh1=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
skl1=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
print('% has a strength value of % and a skill value of %'(char1,strh1,skl1))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong if anyone could help me out that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use percent style formatting, but you forgot the percent between the string and your parameters. In any case, you ought to use `string.format` instead.

Comment: Add a `%` between the string and the tuple of arguments: `'...' % (char1, strh1, skl1)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu there is more problems than that ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, but the OP didn't ask for that. The question is specific, and about a simple typographical error. I've decided to vote to close and comment to give a feedback to the OP as to what was his "syntax error" (although not a `SyntaxError`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your syntax mixed up; to use a string as a template, you need to use the `%` operator *between the string and the tuple*; the placeholders use `%s` to interpolate values as strings:

```
print('%s has a strength value of %s and a skill value of %s' % (char1, strh1, skl1))
```

Without that `%` in between Python sees that as a `'...'()` function call on the string object.

I'd instead recommend you use the newer [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to apply string formatting; it is more readable, uses a method call rather than an operator, and is more flexible:

```
print('{} has a strength value of {} and a skill value of {}'.format(char1, strh1, skl1))
```

Especially when you only have *one* value to implement this is easier to use as you won't fall into the `(oneitem)`-is-not-a-tuple pit that many beginning Python users fall into.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the error something I all too often forget to do (and another +1(if i could) for explaining why they should use the newer str.format method :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 print('%s has a strength value of %s and a skill value of %s'%(char1,strh1,skl1))
```

or

```
print("{0} has a str of {1} and skill of {2}".format(char1,strh1,skl1))
```

(although the numbers inside the curly braces are optional in python2.7 + I number them for compatibility with python <= 2.6 )